# CPU utilization of ReactJS Containers in K8s grows linearly

Tags: reactjs, performance, kubernetes, operating-system, profiling

I have ReactJS containers that utilizes CPU linearly. The window is for 1 week. You can see the CPU growing linearly.

**Breakdown**

- The orange line in the third graph represents the CPU
- The red dotted line in third graph represents 100% of k8s resource requests
- The k8s resource limits is about 3x of requests capacity
- At 300% utilization of requests capacity, you can see that it plateaued (it hit cap)
- Second graph, the network out grows with time for some reason
- First graph represent the number of pods in rotation
- First graph, the first small spike represent a few pods getting cycled out
- First graph, the second big spike represent a deployment and for this reason the utilization went back down

I'm trying to gain some insights from others who may have seen this pattern.
What could have possibly caused this?
How would I profile this application?

[image]

I'm trying to gain some insights from others who may have seen this pattern.

- What could have possibly caused this?
- How would I profile this application?

Comment: 8M/s is a lot of traffic. How many clients are accessing the app?

Comment: By react containers, do you mean SSR?

Comment: i'm doing an SPA rather than SSR @Matt

Comment: @Matt it's sum of all containers but yeah it grows linearly for some reason

Comment: Here's a wild idea: Maybe someone is scraping your data. I have zero context regarding your app and data but that  looks like someone wrote an application to pull everything on that site slowly over 6-7 days at a fixed rate. I've seen it done with car trading sites. They write a scraper and it takes 1 week to pull the whole site and all images / data.

Comment: Do the graphs include the app layer or just the static servers? Are you serving the SPA via the react tools?  Otherwise a production build on a static web server is only likely to display this behaviour with an equivelent linear increase in request load. Look at the access logs.